# Inject a method or a code before executing @Modifying spring jpa

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have a scenario where the data is updated through `Jpa repository.save()` and also using JPQL with `@Modiyfying` annotations if I want to update one or two fields.

I have introduced `EntityListener` to perform operation on `@PreInsert` and `@PreUpdate`. This works like a charm when I use `save()` method.

**CHALLENGE**

I want to execute same code which I execute on `EntityListener` everytime any JPQL is executed through `@Modifying` annotation.

In short I want to inject piece of code for `@Modifying` operations.

Is there any way to do it? I searched but couldn't find one.

Thanks for the time.

Comment: Nope. As executing JPQL completely bypasses the state management of JPA it won't trigger those events. So that isn't possible, depending on what you want to do you can write a regular aspect but that is about it. Assuming you are using hibernate I would strongly suggest instead of writing queries to enable dynamic updates on entities instead.